Is עובר related to the English "over"?
I am now carrying out my second attempt to collect many inexplicable downvotes on this site...
At any rate, the Hebrew verb עובר, which would probably be לעבור in the infinitive if my conjecture that it is Pa'al is correct, sounds suspiciously similar to the English word "over" and means "to pass".
Is there any relation? Googling didn't yield any result, and Wiktionary doesn't seem to know either, leastways not the English version.
EDIT (perhaps some downvotes can thus be reconsidered in order for me not to lose the privilege of asking questions on this site): https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/over#Etymology_1 puts the roots of the English word into immediate geographical proximity to the Hebrew word. And I did know about that when asking the question. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Wiktionary does know the root, עבר, which is cognate with Arabic عبر. The fact that this is a perfectly run-of-the-mill triconsonantal Semitic root, while English over is from an Indo-European comparative of *(h₁)upó- ‘under’(!) would make it virtually impossible to connect the two.

At any rate, the trouble with this question is the same as with your first question: you’re comparing phonetic similarities between two modern, current-day forms, without taking into account what those modern forms come from. In this particular case, the meanings actually happen to coincide fairly well as far back as we can take it, and the forms are primarily incompatible in the difference between Sem. *b and PIE *p, so the problem is less manifest, but the point is general – other seeming parallels would have revealed it much more clearly.

@JanusBahsJacquet Actually, I had done some research; I had known about the Greek relative, and further I supposed that the Hebrew language was sufficiently old for the form to have existed for 2,000 years and more.

The wiktionary page doesn't put "the roots of the English word into immediate geographical proximity to the Hebrew word" and I don't understand how you could possibly read it as such. It's from Proto-Indo-European, a language generally agreed to have been spoken in the North/Northeast coast of the Black Sea (with a minority arguing for positions in the Armenian highland). Are you referring to Old English *ofer? If so, it's worth noting that the use of f there is purely orthographic, it still represented a /v/ sound, as was present ever since Proto-Germanic

This answer comes in three parts. The first examines this particular set of words, the second discusses the types of genuine connections between Hebrew and English words, and the third discusses methodological issues with the approach implied by the question.

I assume you mean עָבַר ʿāḇar (or לַעֲבֹר laʿăḇōr), the paʿal verb from the root עב״ר. Hebrew verbs are generally cited in the 3rd person singular suffix conjugation ("past tense") or infinitive (the latter is more common in Modern Hebrew, the former more common for Biblical Hebrew), not the masculine singular present (originally an active participle), the form that is עוֹבֵר ʿôḇēr.
English over is from Proto-Germanic *uβer (the fricative and original *u vowel demonstrated clearly in Gothic ufar), itself from PIE *(s)upér (whence also Latin super & Greek ὑπέρ hypér which are exact cognates). This is formed from PIE *(s)upó "under, below" (whence also Latin sub and Greek ὑπό hypó) with the same locative-adverbial suffix seen in *n̥dʰér (from which we get English under, Latin infra- & inferior) and *h₁entér (from which we get Latin inter).
The r in English over was originally morphological, but this is not true of the Semitic form, where we only find forms with the r. This doesn't preclude a borrowing into Semitic per se, but as the Semitic is already found in Akkadian as  ebēru this is not chronologically plausible. There are also phonological problems (in particular the PIE has no evidence of any initial consonant that could plausibly be borrowed as an ʿayin, but also in that the Indo-European *p does not seem to correspond well with the Semitic *b).
They are not plausibly related.

In general, English words that are genuinely connected to Hebrew tend to fall into one of three categories:

Recent loanwords. These are generally clear, as is the fact that they're loans.
Loans from some third source (often Greek). These may not be especially clear, as sound change has led their forms to diverge, and the loan into Hebrew may have been a phono-semantic match, meaning the original forms may not even have been especially close. The loan into English is likely also distorted via an intermediate loan into Latin. Their origin in English typically is clear though, as they typically originate in Greek.
Ancient wanderworts. These are rarely obvious. They include things like English steer & Taurus and Hebrew שׁוֹר šôr, or English wine and vine and Hebrew יַיִן  yáyin. The phonological forms here have often diverged dramatically, and whilst in these examples the semantics are still close, this is not always the case.

It follows then that if you have a word in English, which is not readily identifiable as a loan, that is comparable with a Hebrew word, then it is likely a coincidence (something that is a lot more frequent than many people intuitively expect, see this paper by Ringe).

It's also worth noting that the Semitic language family is itself a branch of the larger Afro-Asiatic language family, and so if two connected words were going to be the result of shared inheritance, you'd either need to argue IE was an Afro-Asiatic language or group both IE and Afro-Asiatic as part of an even large macro-family (as is done in the Nostratic proposal). In either case you'd have to compare Indo-European (and not just English) with Egyptian, Amazigh, Cushitic, Chadic, and Omotic, not only with Semitic.
The former proposal (that IE is Afro-Asiatic) has received relatively little attention, but is not generally considered plausible. There were attempts in the 19th century to prove IE a sister to Semitic, but these were largely abandoned once the broader Afro-Asiatic family became accepted, as relationships with other language families (in particular Uralic) seemed more promising than to the other Afro-Asiatic branches.
The latter proposal is not generally accepted, and often considered unprovable by the comparative method. Amongst those "macrocomparativists" working in such long-range comparison though, both are typically included in the Nostratic macro-family, although Indo-European is often said to be more closely related to Uralic & Altaic (with which it is sometimes said to form a "Eurasiatic" phylum) than to Afro-Asiatic. Again, the method of the macrocomparativists is not generally considered reliable, and their conclusions are not generally accepted.

I am aware of the birthday paradox (though I do not deny that I might have fallen victim to it), but "over" in particular does seem to be a not entirely implausible wanderwort, doesn't it?

@AlgebraicsAnonymous it's extremely implausible as a wanderwort. Wanderworts almost always relate to new technology and trade goods (e.g. domesticated cattle, wine, tea, etc). Prepositions and verbs are rarely loaned, let alone in the long chains of loans needed for a wanderwort. And there are the many other problems making this particular case implausible on phonetic grounds

PIE *(s)upó/ér-? I’ve not seen that before – isn’t the s generally taken to be a purely Italic innovation? I don’t remember where I have it from now (I thought De Vaan at least mentioned it, but he doesn’t), but I’ve always had it in my head that it’s supposed to be from *eks upó/upér- with aphaeresis.

@JanusBahsJacquet Adams gives Tocharian B spe "nearby" as from PIE *(s)h4upo "under/below" which he also connects to Armenian hup "near". The Tocharian & Italic would require us to reconstruct an s-mobile if we accept the connection. Likewise the Armenian would probably also require an s-mobile, although depending on exactly what he considers *h4 to be it might come from that instead. Greek is of course ambiguous

de vaan says the s is also found in Greek, but of unclear origin (rejecting comparison to the case of sine ~ en because he etymologises sine differently). Because Celtic lacks the s he says it has to be a specifically Italic development (implicitly assuming Italo-Celtic, but also rejecting the possibility of both variants existing in Italo-Celtic), this also seems to miss examples of irregular loss of initial s in Celtic like the Insular Celtic articles (but not the demonstratives that are of the same origin)
